# Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' exported by the module 'DynamicFormModule'

Tags: angular, module

Angular2 has an ability to generate forms dynamically (Model driven forms) as opposed to manually building the form (template driven).

I have a variation of Dynamic forms in which the entire Form generation functionality is exposed as a module (Angular RC5).

But it breaks with the following error (appears in Dev console)

```
VM849:20 Error: Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' exported by the module 'DynamicFormModule'
```

Here's the plunkr

[Dynamic Form as a Module Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7dwquNzkbvykhsVExitb?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it. There was a typo for DynamicFormComponent. It was spelled as DynamicForm. Corrected it in dynamic-form.module.ts

Answer (score 9):

Had a similar error. Discovered it was caused by a repeated export in one of my index.ts file:

```
export * from './article/article.component';
export * from './body/body.component'; //first export
export * from './cards/cards.component';
export * from './body/body.component'; //repeated export
```

Comment: It helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar error. It was caused by an import in the `NgModule` of my library. Instead of importing it directly, it was imported from the `public_api.ts` file (entry file).

Fixed it by changing

`import { MyDirective } from 'public_api';`

to

`import { MyDirective } from './my-directive/my-directive.directive';`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.
I fixed it by replacing

```
export * from './myComponent'
```

by

```
export {MyComponent} from './myComponent'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because I had created a route file in a child module "A", but didn't import that route file in the root module, even though child module "A" was imported into the root module.

import { A } from 'src/app/module-a/a.module';
import { ARoutes } from 'src/app/module-a/a.routes'; // this was missing in my root app modules

Answer (score 0):

I got the fix for this  from here(https://techoverflow.net/2018/09/19/fixing-angular-error-unexpected-value-undefined-declared-by-the-module/) and it worked for me. 
Trailing coma in my component metadata caused this.